# Libcurl using C

Tags: c, libcurl

I have created a database using Berkeley DB in C. Now I want to use a libcurl function to send the entries in the database to a server. Can anyone suggest me good examples to read which address somewhat similar scenarios or any other material. I researched a bit and the libcurl homepage has some examples, but I am not able to understand them properly, how to use it in my context. I need examples only for "C" language. thanks in advance.

Comment: I doubt anyone would be able to give an example much better than [this](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/postit2.html) unless you add some specifics to your question

Comment: @Hasturkun: the llink you gave above is the only source of reference or can you suggest me some other book or online guide....I just want to familiarize completely with libcurl because i ahve never worked before on it

Comment: There's a [libcurl tutorial](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-tutorial.html), also a reference to the easy api, http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-easy.html

Comment: @Hasturkun: consider providing those comments as an answer instead...

Answer (score 0):

See the [libcurl tutorial](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-tutorial.html) for a overview of libcurl, You may also want to look at the [easy api reference](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-easy.html), as that's what you'll most likely be using